# Good produce/consume strategy in RftG

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

I've been playing Race for the Galaxy with a friend of mine for quite a while, and I've noticed the game seems to be going more and more in favor of a blitzkrieg strategy of conquering as many planets as possible as quickly as possible. Is there a valid produce/consume strategy to counteract this? It seems like it takes far longer to develop a good economy, and even at 2x VP the combat-oriented player still has the advantage of early gains made in prestige, granting them VP and a card every turn.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Winning race for the galaxy without 6 cost developments](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/winning-race-for-the-galaxy-without-6-cost-developments). There are lots of good tips for successful produce/consume.

Comment: are you using the advanced two player rules?

Comment: +1'd because I had exactly the same initial response to RftG.  I wanted there to be a clever way to use my actions more efficiently than my opponents; but in practice, just building lots of stuff as quickly as possible seemed to be a better route to victory.  I'm sure it's actually more subtle than that, but that was definitely my first reaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem you may be facing is that you're trying to play this game strategically.  RftG is must more tactical than, say, Puerto Rico, since your choices of developments and planets is determined by the luck of the draw than being available for purchase.  If you 'set out' to do a produce consume before the game's begun you're putting yourself at a severe disadvantage.

A second thing that may be going wrong is that an engine strategy has a key point where you need to stop building the engine and start running it.  If you feel like you need too much time to build the engine up, perhaps you're building too big of an engine.  Aim for a smaller engine, and then work it that extra couple of times.  You'd be surprised at much even a 20% more 'efficient' engine costs.  Often it's two or more extra produce/consume cycles.

Comment: It's true. You can't have a strategy in RftG. It's all about playing the hand that you are dealt.